# Join string variables in pairs of two using loops in Stata

Tags: string, for-loop, stata

I have a number of string variables `v1 v2 ... v10` each containing a letter. What I want to do is to join `v1` with `v2`, `v3` with `v4` and so on up to `v9` and `v10`. For the single case the code is straightforward `v12 = v1 + v2`. The problem is when I want to do that for all pairs in my dataset. I try the following code but I get wrong results.

```
forval i=1(2)9 {
    gen var`i' = v`i' + v`i+1'
}
```

Here is an example of what I want:

```
v1  v2 v12 
G   G  GG
A   G  AG
G   G  GG
A   A  AG
```

and what I get:

```
    v1  v2 v12 
    G   G  GG
    A   G  AA
    G   G  GG
    A   A  AA
```

For some reason it uses the same variable (`v1`) twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do arithmetic with local macros, even those containing numbers, in that way. It's an oddity that Stata is just ignoring the extra `+1` within the macro reference, as seen in this example:

```
. local i = 1

. di "`i+1'"
1
```

Strictly, `i+1` is not a legal macro name, given the `+` character. Any way, ignore that extra text is what Stata does.

There are various ways to get what you want. Here's one:

```
forval i = 1(2)9 {
    local j = `i' + 1 
    gen var`i' = v`i' + v`j'
}
```

and here's another:

```
forval i = 1(2)9 {
    gen var`i' = v`i' + v`=`i'+1'
}
```

The extra notation

```
`=  '
```

means evaluate the expression given and then insert the results. It's close in spirit to what you were trying.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
clear
input str1 (v1 v2 v3) 
G   G  Q 
A   G  R
G   G  S 
A   A  T 
end
forval i=1/2{
    gen var`i'=v`i'+v`=`i'+1'
    }
list, clean
```

Here's the output.

```
       v1   v2   v3   var1   var2  
  1.    G    G    Q     GG     GQ  
  2.    A    G    R     AG     GR  
  3.    G    G    S     GG     GS  
  4.    A    A    T     AA     AT
```

You will want `forval i=1/9` in your case. The syntax `=`i'+1' used to add 1 to the macro i inline is called the expansion operator in `help macro`.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of odd that you get

```
. local i 4

. dis "`i+1'"
4
```

and that's probably explained by the fact that macro expansion never throws an error.

Anyway, there are macro expansion operators that can be used to increment or decrement a macro (see `help macro`).

```
clear
input str1 (v1 v2 v3) 
G   G  Q 
A   G  R
G   G  S 
A   A  T 
end

local i = 1
while `i' < 3 {
 gen var`i' = v`i' + v`++i'
}
list, clean
```

You can even play with a loop counter:

```
clear
input str1 (v1 v2 v3) 
G   G  Q 
A   G  R
G   G  S 
A   A  T 
end

forval i=1/2{
    gen var`i' = v`i++' + v`i--'
}
list, clean
```